# How to properly chain Vuex actions, and correctly mutate the state between calls?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have a `Vuex` store in my application that defines `getters`, `actions` and `mutations`. Now, one action requests data from an API and commits the received data to the mutation that manipulates the state. This particular action (named `initConfiguration`) loads some metadata and configurations that must be applied to the store before subsequent actions can be executed. In my root component I have some initialization code in the `mounted` lifetime-hook function as follows:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  render: h => h(App),
  mounted() {
    store.dispatch('initConfiguration').then(() => {
      store.dispatch('loadData')
    })
  }
})
```

The problem I am facing is that the state has not been changed before the next action `loadData` gets called, and thus this action fails miserably due to the missing/uninitialized data. Since there will be several actions that may be called eventually, I´d like to avoid to dispatch the `loadData` action right from the `initConfiguration` action (and as I learned, the invocation of actions by a mutation must be avoided).

This is my store implementation...

```js
export default Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    metadata: {
      initialized: false,
      config: { }
    }
  },
  mutations: { 
    setConfiguration(state, config) {
      state.metadata.config = config
      state.metadata.initialized = true
    }
  },
  actions: {
    initConfiguration({commit}) {
      axios.get('configuration').then((response) => {
        commit('setConfiguration', response.data)
      })
    },
    loadData({commit, state}) {
      axios.get(state.metadata.config.tenantDataUrl) // crashes here due to undefined data
        .then((response) => { ... });
    }
  }
})
```

How do I chain actions correctly, and assure that the state gets updated in between?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return your axios promise.  Add a return to each axios call and your existing code will work.

You can also re-write like this

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  render: h => h(App),
  async mounted() {
    await store.dispatch('initConfiguration')
    await store.dispatch('loadData')    
  }
})
```

.

```
export default Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    metadata: {
      initialized: false,
      config: { }
    }
  },
  mutations: { 
    setConfiguration(state, config) {
      state.metadata.config = config
      state.metadata.initialized = true
    }
  },
  actions: {
    async initConfiguration({commit}) {
      const response = await axios.get('configuration')
      commit('setConfiguration', response.data)
    },
    async loadData({commit, state}) {
      const response = await axios.get(state.metadata.config.tenantDataUrl) // crashes here due to undefined data
     // do whatever with response, or try/catch
    }
  }
})
```

If you need the vue template to update at each step, add this

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  render: h => h(App),
  async mounted() {
    await store.dispatch('initConfiguration')
    await this.$nextTick() // cause vue to run getters and update computeds
    await store.dispatch('loadData')    
  }
})
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Of course, I don´t understand yet why. As suggested I changed actions to async and use await instead of chaining promises using then().

Comment: @Matze All actions return a promise.  All promises must return a promise.  Axios returns a promise.  Therefore you can return the result of axios to the action.  `async` and `await` is a modern way to use promises without using `.then() ` and `.catch()` and instead use try/catch.  It makes much cleaner code and much easier to modify later.  In my own vuex work, I define every action as async even if it does nothing async because that gives representation to what vuex is doing with actions even if you do not use promises in the actions